# Redirect already SEO friendly URL to another SEO friendly URL externally using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Part of my .htaccess code is as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]+)*$ nextlevels_state.php?state=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]+)*/([0-9]+)$ nextlevels_state.php?state=$1&page=$2  [NC]
```

This basically redirects URL, `example.com/XX` to `example.com/nextlevels_state.php?state=XX` and `example.com/XX/1` to `example.com/nextlevels_state.php?state=XX&page=1` (internally).

Now, I would like to change the URL structure of the URL from `example.com/XX` to `example.com/nextlevels/XX` and `example.com/XX/1` to `example.com/nextlevels/XX/1`

and I tried changing `.htaccess` to as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^nextlevels/([A-Z]+)*$ nextlevels_state.php?state=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^nextlevels/([A-Z]+)*/([0-9]+)$ nextlevels_state.php?state=$1&page=$2  [NC]
```

However, as the site urls are already indexed in search engines, I would like to know a way to redirect all the traffic from `example.com/XX` to `example.com/nextlevels/XX` (externally) using .htaccess .

Please guide me in this regard. Thank you community :)

Comment: Thanks for detailed and well explained question, keep it up, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only(improving your already done attempts here). Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON

##Rule for redirect to url example.com/nextlevels/XX.
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]+)$ nextlevels/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^nextlevels/([A-Z]+)/?$ nextlevels_state.php?state=$1  [NC,L]

##Rule for redirect to url example.com/nextlevels/XX/1.
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]+)*/([0-9]+)$ nextlevels/$1/$2 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^nextlevels/([A-Z]+)*/([0-9]+)$  nextlevels_state.php?state=$1&page=$2  [NC,L]
```